# How to log a clickable file directory in Node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line

I have a use case where I need to log the file directory onto the console/terminal and when the user clicks on it, that file directory opens up.

For example:

[image]

Clicking on `D:\TMSS\Project\SchuleERP\wars` should open up the respective folder

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I did try out [terminal link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/terminal-link) but that turned out to be working only for URL